# Register content after execution

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm trying to understand how assembly works but I'm having really hard time. Tutorials don't help and I don't have anyone to ask in person so I'm trying to start somewhere.
Can someone explain this to me step by step what is happening in this code and what is the answer to the question below?

What is the content of R16, R17, R18 after executing the following instructions?

```
  ldi   r16, 0xab 
  clr   r17 
  ldi   r18, 0x04 
l1:
  inc   r16 
  dec   r18 
  brne  l1 
  sbrc  r16, 2 
  ldi   r17, 33
  nop
```

I understand first line, we load hex value to register 16, then the register 17 is cleared for some reason, I dont know why, then in third line we load hex 04 for to register 18, then "l1:" is a loop right? And after that I'm not sure what is happening. We increment register 16, decrement register 18 but the rest I dont get it? What the other lines of code do? when the loop ends?

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: `l1` is a label not a loop. Consult an instruction set reference to read about what each instruction does. Use a debugger/simulator to single step the code and observe register state. PS: next time tag with the architecture, I guess it's avr so added that for you.

Comment: I am reading the instruction set reference, If it helped I wouldnt ask.

Comment: Ask a specific question then. Which instruction is unclear, and which part of the manual describing that instruction is unclear?

Comment: Is there more code that follows this? By itself its not immediately clear what this code is trying to achieve without more context. Unless you're looking for a line-by-line explanation of just what you've presented here ... in which case I would agree with Jester. You're better off asking _specific_ questions about where you're confused with the references you're reading.

Comment: I think you may be feeling overwhelmed by what you don’t know. The way to solve that is to break it down. The CPU goes through instructions one at a time, so that’s a good way for you to do it too. You explained everything up to brne. What is confusing you about that instruction? What does the reference say that you don’t understand?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what a specific assembler instruction does, always refer to the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) where all instructions are documented in detail.

The `brne` instruction is a conditional branch ("BRanch if Not Equal").

`brne l1` says: "If not equal, goto label "l1", else continue with the next instruction"

Not equal? What should be "not equal" to what?

This is where a fundamental of many CPUs and assembler languages comes into play:

### The "status register"

In the so-called "status register" (`SREG`) there are a number of flags (single bits), some of them automatically get updated when an arithmetic operation is completed.

The instruction `dec rXY` decrements the register's value and automatically updates the "zero flag" of the status register, i.e. the flag that just indicates if the previous arithmetic instruction resulted in the value 0.

Normal comparisons (instruction `cmp rAB, rXY`) are implemented in hardware like *subtractions*, i.e. `cmp r1, r2` is almost the same as `sub r1, r2`; especially, *both* instructions update the status flags corresponding to the result of the operation. The only difference between the two operations is that `sub` changes `r1`'s value to the result of the subtraction, while `cmp` does not alter any register and just discards the resulting value but still updates the status flags.

If `cmp` is implemented as a subtraction, it can be seen that `cmp r1, r1` (both values equal) yields a result of *zero*, setting the zero flag to `1`. Un-equal values result in non-zero result, i.e. zero flag = `0`.

Hence, `brne ...` branches if the result of the previous operation did *not* yield `0`.

`dec rXY` decrements the register's value and sets the zero flag according to the result, i.e. if, after the decrement, the register contains `0` the zero flag is set (`1`) and `brne ...` effectively means "branch if the result of `dec` is *not* zero".

So the loop is repeated until `r18` gets decremented to zero.

The `sbrc ...` instruction is the mnemomic for "Skip if Bit in Register is Cleared", it causes the next instruction to be skipped or not based on a register bit's value. Look it up in the instruction set manual.